# when entering on the text area showing a submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to when entering in textarea imediately show me the submit button I can use

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name='sub' value="Transfer" style="visibility: hidden" />
```

is there any solution with php or javascript?

Brettz SOLUTION:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<form>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name='sub' value="Transfer" style="visibility: hidden" />
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addEvent (el, type, listener) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    }
    else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on'+type, listener);
    }
    else {
        el['on'+type] = listener;
    }
}
addEvent(document.getElementById('mytextarea'), 'input', function () {
    document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility = 'visible';
});
</script>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to hide the submit button when the text box/area doesn't have focus or have text inside it? Just trying to understand what you are asking for. Thanks

Comment: when it doesn't have text not showing the sub button after entering a text showing to me

Comment: Note that all the solutions calling `$(...)` here are dependent on jQuery being loaded. JSFiddle does not reveal how this is happening in the HTML, but you specifically need to load jQuery into a `<script/>` tag if you want to load jQuery.

Comment: I used it but still have problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name='sub' value="Transfer" style="visibility: hidden" />
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEvent (el, type, listener) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    }
    else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on'+type, listener);
    }
    else {
        el['on'+type] = listener;
    }
}
// Change "focus" to "keypress", if you only want to show the button
//  as soon as the user starts typing, rather than immediately 
//  after they click into the textbox. "input" might be more appealing
//  but this will not work in older browsers. See 
//  http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php
addEvent(document.getElementById('mytextarea'), 'focus', function () {
    document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility = 'visible';
});
</script>
```

Notice I've added a textarea with the id "mytextarea":

...which you can of course change to your own name or needs.

amolv's solution is convenient for quick-and-dirty building of a page. But inline JavaScript (and inline formatting or CSS) is generally frowned upon for real applications, as it is cleaner for the structure of your page (the HTML) to be separated from the behaviors (typically JavaScript, though HTML5 is adding a `<command/>` element which could let you separate the behaviors in a special part of your HTML).

Moving the scripts (and styles) to a separate page, also lets a browser cache (remember) the scripts without needing to reload it when the user visits another page at your site which might reuse the same code. Your server will therefore only need to deliver raw HTML (after the first download) without all the script text mixed inside, thereby speeding up delivery of your page content to the user.

Comment: +1 for using core javascript when the OP made no mention of jQuery.

Comment: Because older browsers (most particular Internet Explorer < 9) don't all support the standard way to add events, we have to see if the standard way (`addEventlistener`) is supported and if not, try using IE's way (`attachEvent`), and if not, it is almost certainly a real dinosaur of a browser which only supports attaching a single event of a given type on an element (in our case, this becomes el.onfocus). That is what the `addEvent` function does. Here we call it specifically to add a `focus` type listener on the textarea element, with the listener handling the change of visibility.

Comment: I'm using firefox I used your code too but it didn't work and I don't know why

Comment: I've amended the text to be complete, since the old code assumed there would be a textarea with a specific ID. It works in Firefox, IE, etc.

Comment: Thank you brettz now how can I force it to when starting to write show me the button?I didn't want by clicking show me the button

Comment: But see my amended note--I should have said "keypress" because "input" is not very well supported across browsers--the one pain of JavaScript is just the implementation support--thus the convenience of using a library like jQuery which handles some of that for you--but also very helpful to know core JS.

Answer (score 3):

```
<textarea rows="" cols="" onfocus="document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility ='visible'" ></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name='sub' value="Transfer" style="visibility: hidden" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to do this quite easily.

```
$('#textToSubmit').focus(function(){
    $('#submit').css('visibility','visible');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CCuVY/1/

**EDIT:** To answer your comment below.

You will need to wrap this in a document ready function, so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put the rest of the code here.
})
```

This also needs to be placed in `<script type="text/javascript">` tags in the `<head>` tags or just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Or you could put it inside a script file.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Comment: Jason I used it but here I have no result I have downloaded a jquery in my folder too that named:jquery-1.4.2.min.js but it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't re-hide an empty text field

Comment: @Negin.  See my edit above.  @Layoric true. but OP did not ask for it to re-hide.

Comment: script is in the form how can it be in the head?

Comment: Jason please see my update edited up there I used your code what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** Here is the live working demo of your answer on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pHyQw/1/)

Comment: Doesn't re-hide an empty text field

Comment: you want to hide the button if the textfield is empty?

Comment: @Coding-Freak, I believe that is what the OP is asking for yes. "when it doesn't have text not showing the sub button"

Comment: can I change it to submit button?

Comment: I used your idea,it doesn't work for me please see my update up there what is wrong in my code?

Comment: coding_Freak I used it again but again it doesn't work,see my update again what is wrong? I can't recognize

Comment: This is because you haven't included the jquery library.

Comment: you need to include this JS file: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: coding_Freak I downloaded JQUERY 1.6 I must include something upthere or not? I saved the file az test8.php and save type as:all files what is wrong now please tell me

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"/>

Comment: use the above code to get the library included, if you are not able to do even this small task, then i guess you need to learn some basics of JS and web development.

Comment: check this thread to learn something about what i am telling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661319/how-to-include-a-js-function-from-an-external-file-inside-a-js-file

Comment: see my update I set the src:src="jquery.min.js" still not working

Comment: i updated the code more. Now you need to put the jquery.min.js in the same folder as the html page.

Comment: I read it But I have many Jqueries and just included one of them You mean it is not correct?

Comment: believe me that i did it but no result You updated which code?

Comment: Your question's code that you have mentioned as Coding-Freak's code

Comment: I USED IT NOW,but no result:"(

Comment: Please learn some basics of JS and HTML. Then attempt for these big things.

Comment: are you angry with me? why?! I'm sorry I tried hard to understand

Comment: @Negin - I know what kind of state you are in. You are a learner. So you should rather try it step by step, instead of trying to leap the mountain at once.

Comment: You yourself suggest a big thing I in my question didn't mentioned Jquery and in down there I told that I don't have experience in Jqueries I knoow just simple functions of java scripts

Comment: Yes I'm beginner in php, you mean the idea of Brettz is very big for me?

Comment: Yes. Its easy for a post-learner. But still a bit tough for you.

Comment: Coding Freak I thank you very much I appreciate your help to make me understand these things I learned a lot from you about Jqueris and including them.

Comment: come online there, here is my mail id - sujitagarwal.com@gmail.com

Comment: I am working on a project about pharmacies,doctors and patients it's a network by transferring a prescribe If you want I can send it to you you will get some hope about me lol! I have many weaknesses but my work is not very bad on that project

Comment: can you please come online on GTALK? because StackOverflow is not a place to chat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but anyway to show the button again in your case you'd remove style="visibility: hidden"

You could use some thing like jquery to make your forms have some affect and make things look a little cool along with some css.

Comment: I know just php and litte javascript now try to understand jqueries in scripts too

Answer (score 0):

You can use key press event for particular text box/ textarea and each time make sure text area has some text in it. On focus will not make sure text box has some text. Or you can use on blur with on focus to but it will not work that much great compare to keyppress

```
$('#yourtextarea').bind('keypress', function() {

  var val = $(this).val();

  if(val != "")

  {

    //show your submit button
    //you can have extra check to make sure submit button is visible or not, if not visible than make it visible

  }
  else

  {

     //hide your submit button

  }


});
```

you need jquery loaded. and given function should be in document.ready